# Dynamicaly created array in if statement inside foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, if-statement, fopen

I'm trying to solve, what seems an easy challenge, in PHP language but have run into a wall. Task is to assemble sort of phone book from .txt file (I called mine stdin.txt). Given `n` names and phone numbers, assemble a phone book that maps friends' names to their respective phone numbers. You will then be given an unknown number of names to query your phone book for. For each `name` queried, print the associated entry from your phone book on a new line in the form `name=phoneNumber`; if an entry for `name` is not found, print `Not found` instead.

The first line contains an integer, `n`, denoting the number of entries in the phone book. 
Each of the  subsequent lines describes an entry in the form of 2 space-separated values on a single line. The first value is a friend's name, and the second value is an 8-digit phone number.

After the n lines of phone book entries, there are an unknown number of lines of queries. Each line (query) contains a `name` to look up, and you must continue reading lines until there is no more input.

**My problem is that dynamicaly created array does not return true inside foreach loop, in `if statement`, but hardcoded array returns true. I have pasted my code, and problems are commented. I feel there is something I'm missing, some simple thing.**

stdin.exe file looks like this:

`3
sam 99912222
tom 11122222
harry 12299933
sam
edward
harry`

Output should be:

`sam=99912222
Not found
harry=12299933`

My code:

```
$stdin = fopen("stdin.txt", "r");
$dictionarie = stream_get_contents($stdin);
$dict_array = explode("\n", $dictionarie);

$entriesNum = $dict_array[0];
$elemNum = count($dict_array);
$pBook = [];
$queries = [];
//$pBook = ["harry" => 12299933, "tom" => 11122222, "sam" => 99912222];
//$queries = ["harry", "sam", "edward"];

for($i = 1; $i <= $entriesNum; $i++)
{
    $entry = explode(" ", $dict_array[$i]);
    $pBook[$entry[0]] = $entry[1];
}

for($i = $entriesNum + 1; $i < $elemNum; $i++)
{
    array_push($queries, $dict_array[$i]);
}

//printing and testing $pBook array
echo "printing and testing \$pBook array\n";
print_r($pBook);
var_dump(array_key_exists("sam", $pBook))."\n";
if(array_key_exists("harry", $pBook))
{
    echo "exists\n\n";
} else
{
    echo "does not exist\n\n";
}

//printing and testing $queries array
echo "printing and testing \$queries array\n";
/*
 * whent testing in_array() function with dynamicaly created array 
 * only last entry will be found, all other elements won't be found, but
 * when using array with hardcoded values (see commented arrays $pBook & $queries), then
 * all elements are found
*/
print_r($queries);
if(in_array("edward", $queries))
{
    echo "exists\n\n";
} else
{
    echo "does not exist\n\n";
}

echo "===============================\n";
echo "foreach loop testing\n\n";
foreach($queries as $i => $query)
{
    // this echo is for control
    echo "=>".$query."\n";

    /*
     * outside of this foreach loop, array_key_exists() function
     * finds all associative keys, but in foreach loop doesn't find them, but
     * if $pBook array is hardcoded (see commented arrays), then associtative keys are found.
     * 
     * for testing purposes I have var dumped $pBook array if assoc key is not found, and all
     * elements are in array.
    */
    if(array_key_exists($query, $pBook))
    {
        echo $query."=".$pBook[$query]."\n\n";
    } else
    {
        var_dump($pBook);
        echo "Not found\n\n";
    }
}

echo "\n===============================\n";

fclose($stdin);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the input to get this to work.

And of course loop over the `$queries` array to look for the persons number.

```
<?php
$stdin = fopen("stdin.txt", "r");
$dictionarie = stream_get_contents($stdin);
$dict_array = explode("\n", $dictionarie);

$entriesNum = $dict_array[0];
$elemNum = count($dict_array);
$pBook = [];
$queries = [];

for($i = 1; $i <= $entriesNum; $i++)
{
    $entry = explode(" ", $dict_array[$i]);
    $pBook[$entry[0]] = trim($entry[1]);
}

for($i = $entriesNum + 1; $i < $elemNum; $i++)
{
    $queries[] = trim($dict_array[$i]);
}

//printing and testing $pBook array
echo "printing and testing \$pBook array\n";
var_dump($pBook);
var_dump($queries);

foreach ($queries as $who) {
    echo 'looking for ' .$who.PHP_EOL;
    if ( array_key_exists($who, $pBook) ) {
        echo $pBook[$who] . PHP_EOL;
    } else {  
        echo 'Not Found'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Guessing that their what they think may be empty at the ends, may very well not be. Good call on the use of `trim()` Riggs. (Edit): Hope you don't mind the edit.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Not at all, at least it was not a spolling Irror this time :)

Comment: Thanks for answer, can you tell me why it didn't work without trim()?